# Can't print spaces with println (it ignores spaces) in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The idea is to get something like this:

```
 012456789 
0|        |0
```

Note the empty spaces before 0 and after 9 in the first line (the pattern then continues but it's not necessary to write it all). First I create the "empty" grid:

```
String[][] grid = new String[12][14]
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++){
        grid[i][k] = "";
    }
}
```

Then I add some numbers:

```
for (int i = 2; i < grid.length; i++){
    grid[0][i] = Integer.toString(i-2);
}
```

Finally, to screen:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j < grid[0].length; j++){
        System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I expect to get:

> -012345678910-

(Assume the - is a space) but I get:

> 01234578910

with no spaces at all. If I change the first part of the code to fill the array with "-" instead of "" I correctly get "-12345678910-" as expected. What's wrong here?

Comment: Your "I expect to get" doesn't have a space before the 10... but more fundamentally, which part of your code do you *expect* to be printing a space?

Comment: You do not print a space anywhere in your code... so it won't show in the output. Also, your expected and actual output is the exact same

Comment: I couldn't even print a correct empty space in my question, lol. I expect to get:
-0123456789-
but I get
0123456789
Assume the - is a space. The question was answered by mattm though. I should use " " instead of "" Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`" "` is not equivalent to `""`. `" "` is a string with a space. `""` is an empty string.